# Peak / local maxima notation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, maxima-minima, numerical-optimization

I was wondering if there exists a common notation for local maxima / peaks of some function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. More specifically, I am looking for something similar to $$x'=\operatorname{arg\,\max_x}f(x)$$
but instead of one global maxima, I am interest in the set of all local maxima. I could imaging a notation similar to
$$\{x'\}=\operatorname{arg\, local\max_x}f(x)$$
(I came up with that myself. Not very happy with it.)

Using this notation (stolen from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max))
$${\displaystyle {\underset {x\in S}{\operatorname {arg\,max} }}\,f(x):=\{x\mid x\in S\wedge \forall y\in S:f(y)\leq f(x)\}.}$$
one could maybe construct something using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima) local maxima definition, also from Wikipedia.

However, this gets convoluted quite quickly. I am looking for something simple and clean. It doesn't have to be super exact, it just needs to convey the idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

arg local max $f(x)$ = $\{x | \exists r>0$ s.t. $\forall y \in (x-r,x+r), f(y) \leq f(x)  \}$