# What is a notation for the histogram's bar corresponding to the "leftmost local maxima"?

Tags: analysis, statistics, maxima-minima

**Question.** What is a notation for the histogram's bar corresponding to the "leftmost local maxima"?

Maybe what proposed in [Peak / local maxima notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012298/peak-local-maxima-notation) can be adapted to denote the bar corresponding to the "leftmost local maxima" in a histogram, but I am not sure about it.

**My attempt.** I was thinking about the following, but I am not sure:

if $f(x)$ is the frequency of occurrence of a quantity $x$ in a histogram, then we might identify the position of the "leftmost local maxima",

$$
{\displaystyle {\underset {x}{\operatorname {min\,(arg\,local\,max} }}\,f(x))
:=
{\operatorname {min\,
\{
x \mid \exists r>0 \, s.t. \forall x' \in (x-r,x+r), f(x') \leq f(x) 
\}}}}
$$

Therefore the histogram's bar corresponding to the "leftmost local maxima" might be written as:

$$
f({\displaystyle {\underset {x}{\operatorname {min\,(arg\,local\,max} }}\,f(x))})
$$

Does this notation make sense?

Comment: any suggestion here? :-)

Comment: Why you need that notation for it? Writing it in words is much better.

Comment: Hi, well, I would like to show some differences with another similar quantity, and the math notation can help for a quicker understanding... just my humble opinion..

Comment: Not my humble opinion. I find that notation a horrendous overkill to describe something that is clear and simple. What is the other similar quantity?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, thats fine :-)